# Kick of Process on Server (In Background) Based on User Form Submit

Tags: php, html, cmd

So I have a page (PHP) that is used by a person to verify some quantities for some product, and then they finalize the page (confirm correct quantities and submit the page).

After they submit (finalize) the quantities, I then have to manually run another page (PHP) that processes this users accepted quantities.

Is there a way to automate the manual portion based on when the user submits their finalized numbers? I want to have this process kick off on the server side so that it does not require them to keep their web page open.

I was thinking of using shell_exec to run a command file that 'runs' the other PHP page, but that would require that the user keeps the page open they submitted the form on correct?

**EDIT**
The Web Server is running WAMP. Forgot to mention this, as it can affect the suggestions/solutions provided.

Comment: Thank you everyone, for your suggestions. I will go research them all so that I can figure out what is the best method to take.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is done by using message queues like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) (as a software) or [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/it/sqs/) (as a service).

This is the application flow of a message queue in Laravel, for example, however the base concept remains the same:

[image: Laravel 5.1 Message Queue application flow]

1. You send some raw data* about what action needs to be fulfilled to the message queue server.
2. You run a daemon listener that watches the message queue and executes a PHP file which has the responsibility to fulfill the action requested.
3. Your PHP file is executed, the action is fulfilled and removed from the queue.

Image Source: http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues

Comment: Please, explain if you downvote, so that people is able to improve their answers.

Answer (score -1):

A fairly easy solution for this would be a task queue, like [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque). You can define the task you'd like to run, and then trigger it to execute after the user submits and finalizes the quantities. It won't require the user to keep a browser window open either.

Answer (score -1):

correct. you can use crontab to execute your php scripts each minute. Some other ideas would be to

1. add the submission to a database where it can form a queue of submitted orders. then iterate through that each minute via crontab.
2. the php processing script that runs after they submit could execute the shell command, and if the process is not expected to take a long time, the shell command can write data to stdout, or to a file and the php page can grab the status from that, which can make it seem less like a dead waiting to load page.
3. in combination with number 2 above your page can perform refreshes updating the status based off of a db query or text file with updates.

I am assuming you have access to crontab. in general most websites use a database to store information like this and then have background processes run to do further processing of the data, kind of sounds like your situation.

also something think about. php has an execution time limit set in the php.ini file. if your processing takes longer then this value it will kill the process.